# flyway:migrate doesn't create tables

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, flyway

I have a java project with Flyway and PostgreSQL integration. There are two scripts in db/migration:

```
--V1__create_table_data_source.sql
CREATE TABLE data_source (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  url TEXT,
  data_type TEXT
);
--V2__create_table_data.sql
CREATE TABLE data (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  data TEXT,
  last_update TIMESTAMP,
  source_id BIGSERIAL REFERENCES data_source
);
```

I use maven script: `mvn clean compile flyway:clean flyway:migrate`, it says: `BUILD SUCCESS`. Then I go to `psql` and do `\dt` in my database, it says that `No relations found.` I cant understand the problem. Is that mean flyway doesn't create tables? Maybe I just use flyway wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the problem was in `<schemas>` section in flyway plugin configuration. I've just removed `<schemas>` section completely, and now it works!